# How to use a skin from the main application in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have an application with a SWF loader.
From the loaded SWF file, I'm accessing public variables from the main application with this:

```
[Bindable] public var global:Object = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication;

Alert.show(global.myvar);
```

This all works perfect.

---

I have a MXML skin file (for buttons) in a directory called 'skins' in the main application.
Is it possible to use this skin in the child applications?

---

I've already tried this, unfortunately not working:

```
[Bindable] public var global:Object = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication;

<s:Button label="My Text" skinClass="{global.skins.menuButtons}" />
```

And this, but then it can't compile anymore:

```
[Bindable] public var global:Object = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication;

<s:Button label="Button 1" skinClass="global.skins.menuButtons" />
<s:Button label="Button 2" skinClass="FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.skins.menuButtons" />
```

---

Is it possible what I want in another way or do I have to copy the skin to the all the projects where I want to use the skin?

Thanks.

Comment: One option can be to make a swc having all the skin classes and mark that swc to be loaded as rsl. That way you'd have skin.swc, main_app.swf and child_app.swf. Since the swc is rsl, it won't add to the weight of any of the swf and the compiler would be happy too. Otherwise, you can get class instance of skins from mainApp by getDefinitionByName and use that class to create skin instance. Of course, you won't have any compile time check in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already fixed the problem.

In my main SWF file, I'm defining a public variable as class:

```
public var menuButtons:Class = skins.menuButtons;
```

And in the children SWF files, I'm referring to this variable with FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication:

```
[Bindable] public var global:Object = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication;

<s:Button label="My Text" skinClass="{global.menuButtons}" />
```

Apparently it is not possible to refer directly to the skin with *global.skins.menuButtons*.